# Find address of value in a struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct called message:

```
typedef unsigned char messageType;
struct message{
    message() : val(0), type(home),nDevice(0) {}
    messageType type;
    _int32 val;
    char nDevice;
};
```

And i have a pointer to that struct:

```
message* reply;
```

How can I get the address of reply.val so I can memcpy to it?
eg:

```
    memcpy(inBuf+2,address here,4);
```

Comment: Dunno if it was intentional or not, but your memcpy() line above is set to copy data *from* (address here) to (inBuf+2).  If you want to copy bytes *to* (address here) you should swap the positions of the first two arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
memcpy(inBuf+2, &reply->val, sizeof(reply->val));
```

will do because the precedence of `->` is higher than address-of `&`.

If you are not sure about operator precedence, just use parenthesis, readability is more important:

```
memcpy(inBuf+2, &(reply->val), sizeof(reply->val));
```

Thanks for @DyP's comment, note that it's better to use `sizeof(reply->val)` than the literal `4`.

Comment: Wouldn't `sizeof(reply->val)` be more appropriate than the literal `4`?

Comment: @DyP Sure, I'm following what the OP is using. I'll update it.

Answer (score 3):

Try `&(reply->val)`.

Be aware that the compiler can add padding to structs which will potentially ruin your plan, however.

Comment: Thanks. It is safe to copy an array of 4 unsigned chars directly to a _int32 though?

Comment: Probably, depending on how portable you need it to be. The endianness of the target system might break things for you.

Comment: @Tim If the contents of the array have been `memcpy`ed from another `_int32` and you copy this content to an `_int32`, everything is fine. Else, it depends on your compiler.

Comment: This is for a normal PC (little endian) talking to a liner actuator over rs232 which takes its value in little-endian

Comment: If you have that tight of control over your environment, you can use compiler directives to disable padding. I'm not familiar enough with the pitfalls of using `memcpy` in this way to say what other issues could crop up.

Answer (score 2):

```
memcpy(&(reply->val), address, sizeof(address))
```